# Notifications - Alternate to Object.observe?

Tags: javascript, notifications

Trying to build a small component that sends you notifications via the `Notifications Object` on a small web app.
So, once a private message has been received in a group, if the value of the field has incremented or changed, then display a notification.

This works fine if you refresh the page but it is not running asynchronously.

With `Object.observe()` being deprecated, would somebody please explain how I would implement this? I don't quite understand how to do so with Proxies.

Thanks a lot!!

shortened for brevity

```
var myGroup = 0;
var notificationCount = [];

notificationCount.push({'myGroup': myGroup});
localStorage.setItem('notificationCount', JSON.stringify(notificationCount));
var storedCounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notificationCount");

setTimeout(function() {
    var newCountMyGroup = parseInt($('.myGroup .wrapper').text());

    if(newCountMyGroup > 0 && storedCounts[0].myGroup !== newCountMyGroup) {
        notify('New Post in My Groups', 'linkHere')
    }
}, 800);

function notify(alertMessage, alertLink) {
    if(Notification.permission !== "granted") {
        Notification.requestPermission();
    } else {
        var notificationMyGroup = new Notification(...);
        notificationMyGroup.onclick = function(){
            window.open(alertLink);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I only just began this and my initial thought was to use Object.observe - knowing it's deprecation however I need an alternative.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am trying to observe the change of the text field stored in newCountMyGroup which is changed when a new message has been received. If it has changed, send a notification. Ignore that last bit will edit out.

Comment: Isn't `newCountMyGroup` a number? How does it have a text field in it? *(Not trying to be difficult. Just trying to understand what you really need here.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No I understand that's fine. I'm just going off the HTML structure I got given and the way the data is presented I am grabbing the value from a div element on the page. When a message is received it automatically updates from 0 to 1 etc.

Comment: So you want a notification when the *div* changes? (Although you're already checking that every 800ms.) I'm not seeing a use case so far for either `Object.observe` or `Proxy`. But I'm also feeling thick, like I'm missing the point. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I may have gone about it the wrong way, but I want a Notification to display when the div's value changes due to a message. The setTimeout function isn't running properly. The desired outcome is for it to run async as soon as a message is received. This currently only works once you refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> I want a Notification to display when the div's value changes due to a message. The setTimeout function isn't running properly. The desired outcome is for it to run async as soon as a message is received. This currently only works once you refresh the page.

I read past it three times, but your current code schedules a *single* timed callback on page load for 800ms later. `setTimeout` just sets a one-off timer. If you want that to be repeated, you use `setInterval` instead.

So if you want to do this with polling, `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` will do it.

If you want to do it without polling, you don't need `Object.observe` or `Proxy` because what you want to observe is a *DOM element* (the `div`), not a JavaScript object. Fortunately, there's a tool for that: [Mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You could watch for `childList` changes to all `.myGroup` elements, which would tell you when a new `.wrapper` was added, and/or watch for `characterData/childList` notifications on the `.wrapper` elements, which will tell you when their text is changed.

Here's a quick example of both, see comments:

```js
var wrapperId = 0;

// Our function for when a .myGroup's child list changes
function myGroupModificationCallback(records) {
  // (Your real code would go here)
  console.log("Saw a modification to " + records[0].target.id);
  // If you want to watch wrappers, you'd set them up by calling hookUpWrapperObservers
  hookUpWrapperObservers();
}

// Hook up obervers to any  `.myGroup` elements that don't have them yet
function hookUpMyGroupObservers() {
  $(".myGroup").each(function() {
    var group = $(this);
    var ob = group.data("ob");
    if (!ob) {
      ob = new MutationObserver(myGroupModificationCallback);
      ob.observe(this, {
        childList: true
      });
      group.data("ob", ob);
    }
  });
}

// Our function for when a .wrapper's character data changes
function wrapperNotificationCallback(records) {
  // (Your real code would go here. Note you may get multiple records for the same wrapper.)
  var changes = Object.create(null);
  records.forEach(function(record) {
    changes[record.target.id] = record.target;
  });
  Object.keys(changes).forEach(function(id) {
    console.log(id + " changed: " + $(changes[id]).text());
  });
}

// Hook up observers to any .wrapper elements that don't have them yet
function hookUpWrapperObservers() {
  $(".myGroup .wrapper").each(function() {
    var wrapper = $(this);
    var ob = wrapper.data("ob");
    if (!ob) {
      var ob = new MutationObserver(wrapperNotificationCallback);
      ob.observe(this, {
        characterData: true,
        childList: true
      });
      wrapper.data("ob", ob);
      console.log(this.id + " received: " + $(this).text());
    }
  });
}

// Initial setup
hookUpMyGroupObservers();
hookUpWrapperObservers();

// Testing/demo: Add two wrappers to the first group and one to the
// second Update all three of them three times, then stop
setTimeout(function() {
  addWrapper("#group1");
  setTimeout(function() {
    addWrapper("#group2");
    setTimeout(function() {
      addWrapper("#group1");
    }, 300);
  }, 300);

  function addWrapper(selector) {
    var wrapper = $("<div class=wrapper>1</div>");
    wrapper[0].id = "wrapper" + (++wrapperId);
    $(selector).append(wrapper);
    var counter = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      wrapper.text(parseInt(wrapper.text()) + 1);
      if (++counter == 3) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 300);
  }
}, 300);
```

```html
<div class="myGroup" id="group1"></div>
<div class="myGroup" id="group2"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Mutation observer support is [good in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver). IE9 and IE10 implemented the previous mutation *events*, and so there are polyfills that use events to provide a subset of observer behavior on those browers. For IE8 and earlier, you'll need to poll.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for your detailed response and patience! @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dead simple demo of using a proxy.

```js
let o = {a: 1, b: 2};

let p = new Proxy(o, {
  get: (target, name) => {
    console.log(`getting ${name} on ${target}: ${target[name]}`)
    return target[name];
  },
  set: (target, name, value) => {
    console.log(`setting ${name} to ${value} on ${target}`)
    target[name] = value;
  }
});

p.a;     // getting a on [object Object]: 1
p.a = 5; // setting a to 5 on [object Object]
p.a;     // getting a on [object Object]: 5
```

Instead of doing a `console.log`, connect this to whatever event handler you'd like.

You could do something like ...

```
set: (target, name, value) => {
  event.emit(`set:${name}`, target, value, target[name]);
  target[name] = value;
}
```

... or whatever works for you.